# Pytest and gcloud libraries throwing DefaultCredentialsError

Tags: python, google-bigquery, pytest, gcloud, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to write a unit test for my Flask application, however I'm having issues with these two google libs:

- google-cloud-secret-manager
- google-cloud-bigquery

As soon a new instance of `bigquery.Client` or `secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient` is created, I get this error:

> ERROR tests/integration/health/test_ping.py::test_ping -
> google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Your default
> credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials,
> see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc
> for more information.

I'm using the [dependency_injector](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/), and I have this container:

```
from dependency_injector import containers, providers
from google.cloud import bigquery, secretmanager

class Core(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    bigquery_client = providers.Singleton(bigquery.Client)
    secretmanager_client = providers.Singleton(secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient)

    secret_manager_repository = providers.Singleton(
        SecretManagerRepository, secretmanager_client=secretmanager_client
    )

    products_repository = providers.Singleton(
        ProductsRepository,
        bigquery_client=bigquery_client,
    )


class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    wiring_config = containers.WiringConfiguration(__name__)

    core = providers.Container(
        Core,
    )
```

And then I use the Container above when creating the app:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    container = Container()
    container.core.init_resources()
    app.container = container

    register_blueprints(app)

    return app
```

This is my test:

```
def test_ping():
    """
    GIVEN there is a Flask app running
    WHEN the '/api/v1/' path is requested (GET)
    THEN check that the response is valid
    """
    app = create_app()
    response = app.test_client().get("/api/v1/health")
    assert b"ok" in response.data
```

I can't keep a key.json file in my codebase, with my gcloud credentials. How can I fix this error?

I've tried mocking the 2 gcloud clients, but it didn't work:

```
with mock.patch('google.cloud.bigquery.Client') as mock_client, \
        mock.patch('google.cloud.secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient') as mock_secret_client:
    mock_client.return_value = None  
    mock_secret_client.return_value = None

    app = ...
```

Any ideas?